# Trouble Association with insert using integration test in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

### Problem

I am trying to create integration test. I have three table one is product other is manufacturer and other is mapping table for product_manufacturer.

when I try to create a product and then assign manufacturer I have  to pass productId in my case productId is auto incremented and i have no clue how to pass it. now my question is how I achieve the solution of this problem in best possible way.

### Entity

```
 public partial class Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Product()
        {
            Category_Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping = new HashSet<Category_Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping>();
            Product_Category_Mapping = new HashSet<Product_Category_Mapping>();
            Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping = new HashSet<Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping>();
            Product_Manufacturer_Mapping = new HashSet<Product_Manufacturer_Mapping>();
            Product_Picture_Mapping = new HashSet<Product_Picture_Mapping>();
            ProductPriceHistories = new HashSet<ProductPriceHistory>();
            ProductReviews = new HashSet<ProductReview>();
            ProductTags = new HashSet<ProductTag>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        public string FullDescription { get; set; }

        public string AdminComment { get; set; }

        public bool ShowOnHomePage { get; set; }

        [StringLength(400)]
        public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

        [StringLength(400)]
        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }

        public bool AllowCustomerReviews { get; set; }

        public int ApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

        public int NotApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

        public int ApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

        public int NotApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

        public bool MarkAsNew { get; set; }

        public DateTime? MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

        public DateTime? MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        public bool Published { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedOnUtc { get; set; }

        public int ClickCount { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Category_Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping> Category_Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product_Category_Mapping> Product_Category_Mapping { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping> Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product_Manufacturer_Mapping> Product_Manufacturer_Mapping { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product_Picture_Mapping> Product_Picture_Mapping { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductPriceHistory> ProductPriceHistories { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductReview> ProductReviews { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }
    }
```

### Image

[image]

### code

```
[TestMethod]
public void InsertProduct_Manufacturer_Graph()
{
    using (var dataContext = new PriceHunterDataContext())
    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(dataContext))
    {
        var manufacturerRepository = new Repository<Manufacturer>(dataContext, unitOfWork);
        var manufacturer = manufacturerRepository.Query(x => x.Name == "Apple").Select().FirstOrDefault();

        var name = "Test Product";
        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = name,
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added,
            Product_Manufacturer_Mapping = new[]
            {
        new Product_Manufacturer_Mapping()
        {
            ProductId = 1,//here is the issue. It is auto increment key
            ManufacturerId = manufacturer.Id,
            IsFeaturedProduct = true,
            DisplayOrder = 1,
        },
    }

        };
        var productRepository = new Repository<Product>(dataContext, unitOfWork);
        productRepository.InsertOrUpdateGraph(product);
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        var insertedpermission = productRepository.Query(x => x.Name == name).Select().FirstOrDefault();
        Assert.IsNotNull(insertedpermission);
        Assert.IsTrue(insertedpermission.Name == name);
        Assert.AreEqual(name, insertedpermission.Name);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you navigate the Product property of the object of Product_Manufacturer_Mapping class?

Comment: @MamunReza Entity Added in the question

Comment: Ideally one Manufacturer would have multiple Products, but from your code it seems one Product can have list of Manufacturers. Is this how it should be in your case?

Comment: Flow is when user add product it has to add manufacturer of that product from the list